# LUKS: Enter passphrase and nothing happens

Tags: grub2, gentoo, luks, cryptsetup

I've installed gentoo on my new laptop. I've got an LUKS-encrypted root partition (/dev/sda3). Cryptsetup (USE="gcrypt") is installed. Essential cryptographic API is compiled in kernel. Kernel and initrd image are built using genkernel-next (--luks --gpg).

I use GRUB2 and these kernel options: `root=/dev/ram0 crypt_root=/dev/sda3 real_root=/dev/mapper/root rootfstype=ext4`

I also tried to omit `rootfstype`, and `root=/dev/mapper/root` (no `real_root`), but nothing has changed.

When I boot my system it asks me for my password:

`Enter passphrase for /dev/sda3:` ... and after I type (in)correct password nothing happens: I can type any symbol infinitely.

Any ideas? I can boot with live-cd and successfully mount this encrypted volume with `cryptsetup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by rebuilding **initrd** image using *genkernel-next* with `--lvm` option.